# Composer conflicts when installingstof/doctrine-extensions-bundle on symfony 5

Tags: composer-php

when trying to install via `composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` I get a bunch of messages telling me that there is no way to install the package: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

Part of the output is:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - doctrine/common 2.2.1 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.2 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.3 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.3.0 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/cache (locked at 1.10.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Installation request for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.4.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.4.0 requires gedmo/doctrine-extensions ^2.3.4 -> satisfiable by gedmo/doctrine-extensions[v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.11, v2.4.12, v2.4.13, v2.4.14, v2.4.15, v2.4.16, v2.4.17, v2.4.18, v2.4.19, v2.4.2, v2.4.20, v2.4.21, v2.4.22, v2.4.23, v2.4.24, v2.4.25, v2.4.26, v2.4.27, v2.4.28, v2.4.29, v2.4.3, v2.4.30, v2.4.31, v2.4.32, v2.4.33, v2.4.34, v2.4.35, v2.4.36, v2.4.37, v2.4.38, v2.4.39, v2.4.4, v2.4.40, v2.4.41, v2.4.42, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.10 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
```

I have been installing, in this order:

```
composer require profiler --dev 
composer require logger 
composer require debug --dev 
composer require annotations 
composer require sec-checker --dev 
composer require twig 
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev 
composer require doctrine 
composer require form
composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
```

The latter is the first that threw an error

composer:json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.9",
        "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^6.0",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.21",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.1",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.1",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share more details about the other packages you've already installed?

Comment: Please add all information to your question by editing it. Also, it could help to see the version constraints from your `composer.json` - can you add them?

Comment: Please use `composer why-not` to check if there are any more conditions that apply

Comment: sorry Nico. I am afraid I don't know how to use why-not.

composer why-not stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle

just gives me a "Could not find package "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through that list of requirements, you've installed `doctrine/common` in v3. The latest stable version of `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` is not yet compatible with that, which you can see in [some](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/2168) [issues](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/2130).

You have two options: either wait for some more days or weeks until that package is made compatible, or downgrade `doctrine/common` before to v2. This is possible by using

`composer require doctrine/common:"^2.11" doctrine/persistence:"^1.3"`

Comment: Nico, that was great. It worked for me. Thx a lot.
And for updating in a few weeks I just use composer update or do I have to use a different command?

Comment: Well, Composer works a bit strange here: technically, you can remove the two Doctrine packages right away, now, directly. Updating the extensions package works like usual afterwards, when the update is released